# Gradle, how to encrypt SWF file

Tags: flash, encryption, ant, gradle

I have an ant task `<encrypt file="${something}.swf"/>`. I need the same for Gradle however Google returns zero results about this...

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use ant from gradle as described [here](http://gradle.org/current/docs/userguide/ant.html). So I guess you are looking for something like this:

```
ant.encrypt(file:"${something}.swf")
```

If it doesn't work you can always import your ant build file as described further down in the manual.